# Sha256 hash in Portable Library .Net

Tags: .net, windows-phone-8, windows-8, portable-class-library

I need to compute the hash of a byte array in a Portable Library.

I'm trying to find an equivalent of System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256Managed for my Portable library targeting .NET 4.5 + win 8 + WP 8.0 .

I tried  the PclContrib but it seems I can't install it for a library targeting those platforms.

Is there any library providing hash algorithms implementations which can be referenced in the context of a Portable Library?

Thanks

Comment: You could use BouncyCastle, there seem to be PCL versions of it (not sure if there is an official PCL version). Or you could simply rip SHA-256 out if BC and use it directly.

Comment: Thanks CodesInChaos, could you tell me please where can I find the Sha256 class to compute the hash in this Library?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use this port of [Bouncy Castle](http://w8bouncycastle.codeplex.com/). AArnott has prepared a [PCL Version](http://w8bouncycastle.codeplex.com/workitem/1638) that is not yet accepted but which might help you. 
You can also integrate some [mono source code](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/corlib/System.Security.Cryptography/SHA256Managed.cs) directly into yours.

A Bouncy Castle sample :

```
        var data = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("test");
        Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Digests.Sha256Digest hash = new Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Digests.Sha256Digest();
        hash.BlockUpdate(data, 0,data.Length);
        byte[] result = new byte[hash.GetDigestSize()];
        hash.DoFinal(result, 0);
```

**Update:**
I do not maintain my original port and I strongly recommend using one the available ones on GitHub such as : https://github.com/onovotny/BouncyCastle-PCL . It supports way more platforms as well.

**Update 2:**
As of today, I would rather recommend the usage of [PCLCrypto](https://github.com/AArnott/PCLCrypto). This library is maintained by AArnott (who originally helped me with Bouncy castle PCL support). The main advantage of this library is that, thanks nuget bait and switch, it will use **native** crypto **APIs** instead of managed slow and potentially insecured implementations. Complete list of supported Algorithms is available [here](https://github.com/AArnott/PCLCrypto/wiki/Algorithms-X-platforms-support).

**Update 3:**
Net Standard based class libraries should now be the answer for most use cases. PCLCrypto seems to remain the best when it comes to Xamarin development.

Comment: I spent the last hour trying to import the mono cryptography part in my project but there are just too many dependencies. and I can't find any useful class in Bouncy Castel library.

Comment: I edited my comment to add a bouncy castle sample.

Comment: Yep ... it's working!!! Thanks. Sorry I didn't knew how to use the class ... I didn't knew BlockUpdate is used to load the byte array.

Comment: You're welcome, this library is quite not straightforward :)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps You are looking for `HashAlgorithmProvider`

Does this work for you?

```
   private void HandleHashClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // get the text...
        var inputText = this.textInput.Text;

        // put the string in a buffer, UTF-8 encoded...
        IBuffer input = CryptographicBuffer.ConvertStringToBinary(inputText, 
            BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8);

        // hash it...
        var hasher = HashAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm("SHA256");
        IBuffer hashed = hasher.HashData(input);

        // format it...
        this.textBase64.Text = CryptographicBuffer.EncodeToBase64String(hashed);
        this.textHex.Text = CryptographicBuffer.EncodeToHexString(hashed);
    }
```

for more Refrence you can go [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/Desktop/windows.security.cryptography.core.hashalgorithmprovider.openalgorithm)

Comment: Isn't that WinRT/metro only?

Comment: no it can work for both windows and windows phone. just see Requirements in Given link

Comment: thanks for the fast answer but sadly that's for windows phone 8.1 and I need to support wp 8.0